# Override Material UI styles results in "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to follow the [examples](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) to override the material -ui style for the 'chip' component in react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip/Chip';
import {withStyles} from 'material-ui/styles'

const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    paddingTop: '25px',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  }
};

class MyChip extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

     render() {

        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
                <Chip 
                    classes={{ root: classes.root }}
                    key={this.props.idx}
                    onRequestDelete = {this.props.onRequestDelete}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </Chip>
        )
    }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(MyChip);
```

This is resulting in the following error : **Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**

Does anyone know how to do this properly? Ive followed the examples as well as other stack overflow [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831450/how-to-overwrite-classes-and-styles-in-material-ui-react) with no luck.

Comment: can you attach an image of your error?

Comment: maybe it is just you imported wrong Chip. I guess it is import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

Comment: Im not sure what the difference is, but the other import style does not work for me. Ive been using the chip component for a while just fine, so i don't suspect the import statement.

Comment: The error is specifically calling out the `export default withStyles(styles)(MyChip);` line of code.

Comment: I see, which version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: material-ui@0.20.2 . Perhaps i need to upgrade

Comment: yes, try that. I think your version is obsolete. they moved to another version with new name

Comment: The examples you linked to are for version 3.9.3 and the styling approach was significantly different prior to version 1.0.